# БД+документооборот (проектирование), способ хранения сотрудников и наименование их отделов. Актуальность данных

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

Делаю документооборот между несколькими отделами (я их уже связал).
 Есть таблицы с сотрудниками (и их «*ID*»), и отделами (и их «ID») и другие таблицы с документами.
В каждом документе/таблице учавствует сотрудник и отдел.

**Вопрос**:
В каком виде лучше(правильнее) хранить в каждом документе/таблице сотрудника и отдел?  (В виде ID на соответствующие классификаторы или в явном виде (тип поля string))?
…
Ну как бы ФИО сотрудника, в процессе работы не должно меняться (хотя женщины могут менять фамилии) их можно хранить в виде ID.
А вот отделы могут со временем изменять названия, и тут как бы уже нужно в каждый документ вставлять явно «название» отдела. Т.е. **когда документ попадает в архив**, у него желательно сохранить старые данные, т.е. данные которые были актуальны еще до попадания в архив.

У кого какие предложения будут?

Comment: ну так создайте таблицу employments и храните в ней ссылку на персону, ссылку на подразделение, ссылку на должность (или текстовое название должности), дату начала, дату окончания, ставку и т.п.

Comment: Нет, меня интересует вопрос актуальности данных в документах, а также архивных документах при изменении их в классификоторе... Например, с одним начальником отдела создавался документ,  потом он попал в архив, потом у этого отдела поменялся начальник или поменялось название отдела. Напомню архивные данные **менять нельзя**

Comment: в моём предложении легко вычислить кто какую должность занимал на определённую дату (например, на дату редактирования). изменения в названии отдела/фамилии легко отследить если в таблице employments рядом с идентификаторами персоны и подразделения положить и идентификатор версии (версии, естественно, тоже надо будет хранить и лучше отдельно от актуальных записей)

Comment: спасибо я рассмотрю ваше предложение. Хотя я бы наверное всетаки залез бы в избыточность данных. Например при добавлении/редактировании документа, я просто из классфикатора подставляю актуальные данные в документ (не ссылки на них, а в лоб) и все и тогда и доп. таблицу делать не нужно

Comment: такой подход тоже имеет право на существование. но на сколько глубокой должна быть копия данных - автор правки + все подразделения до корня? а начальник автора? а если поменяют требования и захотят условного визирующего? начальник визирующего? избыточность превратиться в недостаточность. а сможешь ли ты гарантировать, что в момент сохранения новой версии документа структура подразделений в БД была актуальной? а что если оператор БД подразделений/кадровик/etc взял больничный на денёк? подумой, короч

Answer (score 0):

Вот что надумал, например:

В классификаторе есть отдел "РР-1", с ним сохраняются документы, попадают в архив - все замечательно.

В классификаторе отделов убираю возможность редактировать название отдела, а также скрываю кнопку "удалить".

Если допустим отдел хотят переименовать в "ММ-2" (на здоровье). - я просто добавляю строку с новым отделом "ММ-2". И тогда документы начинают сохраняться с новым ID.

Конечно придется в классификатор отделов добавить поле, по которому я буду видеть, что эти отделы с разными ID, это один и тот же отдел. Ну и конечно, добавил бы поле "архивный" (статус) - чтоб отдел с старым названием не отсвечивал.

Впринципе с изменением ФИО людей, тоже такая история...

Как-то так.

Comment: то же, что я писал про версионность, только повёрнутое на 90 град. не забудь учесть в схеме, что отделы сливают-разделяют

Comment: @norbornen, "сливают-разделяют" - имеется ввиду: "объединяют с другими отделами" и "дробят на более мелкие"? Так это создание нового отдела. А в дополнительном поле классификатора, можно указывать ID начального/предка отдела. В принципе, если его сделать типа "string", то можно записывать через запятую все ID предков отдела